# Unexpected escaped CRs inserted with XSLT output-method="text" transform

Tags: xml, xslt, msxml, msxml6

My question here is what the logic of the following behavior might be, or if it's a bug (in MSXML6 under Windows) even what failure of logic could underpin such a bug.

Consider the input XML file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <item>first item</item>
    <item>second item</item>
</root>
```

The following XSLT attempts to extract the items in text format, one per line, with the standard Windows CR-LF line endings.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [<!ENTITY eol "<![CDATA[&#xD;&#xA;]]>">]> <!-- (a) !?? -->

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" media-type="text/plain"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements='*'/>
<xsl:template match="item"> <!-- list items, one per line -->
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&eol;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, the output that I am getting includes extraneous escaped CRs literally output as `"&#13;"` at the end of each line.

```
first item&#13;
second item&#13;
```

The question, again, is about the particular behavior above, which I find quite odd. I am specifically not asking for alternatives or workarounds, in fact variations thereof look to be working fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [<!ENTITY eol "<![CDATA[&#xA;]]>">]> <!-- (b) works  -->
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [<!ENTITY eol "&amp;#xA;">]>         <!-- (c) no newlines in output -->
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [<!ENTITY eol "&#x26;#xA;">]>        <!-- (d) works  -->
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [<!ENTITY eol "&#xA;">]>             <!-- (e) no newlines in output -->
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [<!ENTITY eol "&#xD;&#xA;">]>        <!-- (f) works  -->
```

---

[ *EDIT* ] Following is the minimal JScript code to duplicate the issue.

```
var vArgs = WScript.Arguments;
var xmlFile = vArgs(0);
var xslFile = vArgs(1);

var xmlDOMDocProgID = "MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0";

var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject(xmlDOMDocProgID);
xmlDoc.setProperty("NewParser", true);
xmlDoc.validateOnParse = false;
xmlDoc.async = false;
xmlDoc.load(xmlFile);

var xslDoc = new ActiveXObject(xmlDOMDocProgID);
xslDoc.setProperty("NewParser", true);
xslDoc.setProperty("ProhibitDTD", false);
xslDoc.validateOnParse = false;
xslDoc.async = false;
xslDoc.load(xslFile);

WScript.StdOut.Write(xmlDoc.transformNode(xslDoc));
```

Assuming it's saved as `test.js` and the xml/xslt files are `test.xml` and `test.xslt` respectively, the transformation at the cmd prompt can be run as,,,

```
C:\etc>cscript //nologo test.js test.xml test.xslt
first item&#13;
second item&#13;

C:\etc>
```

Comment: How do you use/run MSXML exactly? But the whole approach of having output method `text` on the one hand but then use `disable-output-escaping` and entities and CDATA seems rather convoluted.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I edited the post to include a trimmed down JScript equivalent of the respective code. FWIW the source XSLT has some elements left over from debugging, for example `disable-output-escaping` makes no difference whether present or not, nor does `media-type`. What puzzles me most are those escaped CRs in a (supposedly) plain text output.

Comment: The result is indeed rather odd, when I comment out the call `xslDoc.setProperty("NewParser", true);` the character references in the transformation result are gone. So that "new parser" seems to have some rather odd parsing behaviour, according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms767616%28v%3dvs.85%29 it was introduced in MSXML 4 and "is faster and more reliable than the old one". I will try to run some test that doesn't use XSLT at all to see whether it is just a parser bug.

Comment: @MartinHonnen `the whole approach ... seems rather convoluted` Just curious, what would you consider to be the least convoluted approach? I know of workarounds for the posted XSLT question, but those appear to work mainly because the text output looks to be routed via a text stream that normalizes line endings. Meanwhile, I have tinkered some more with your XML-only parsing experiment, and I have found no way to inject a literal CR in the element text value. This is mostly academic for me at this point, but XML is not my mother tongue and I am curious to learn the less obvious ins and outs.

Comment: In the context of XSLT, if I want to define a certain line ending to use it at different places of the text output method I would define a parameter, as done in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyRYYiA, so `<xsl:param name="eol" select="'&#13;&#10;'"/>` (you need to use character references in there as they are not normalized) and then `<xsl:value-of select="$eol"/>`. I have used a similar JScript program to yours to test with MSXML 3 and MSXML 6 but done `var result = xmlDoc.transformNode(xslDoc); var match = result.match(/\r\n/g);WScript.StdOut.Write(match.length);` and it shows 2.

Comment: Thanks. That's a bit more typing than the entity notation but, you're right, it looks to be the safest, most portable way. FWIW in the MSXML world, the only construct that appears to work with all of v3.0, v4.0 and v6.0 regardless of `NewParser` seems to be `<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [<!ENTITY eol "<![CDATA[&#xA;]]>">]>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a bug of MSXML 6 and the "new parser" you enable there with `xslDoc.setProperty("NewParser", true);`. Even without using any XSLT at all you can load a document like

```
<!DOCTYPE root [<!ENTITY eol "<![CDATA[&#xD;&#xA;]]>">]>
<root>&eol;</root>
```

with MSXML 6 and the "new parser" and check the `text` property of the root/document element

```
var xmlDOMDocProgID = "MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0";

var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject(xmlDOMDocProgID);
xmlDoc.setProperty("NewParser", true);
xmlDoc.setProperty("ProhibitDTD", false);
xmlDoc.validateOnParse = false;
xmlDoc.load('cdata-input2.xml');

WScript.Echo(xmlDoc.documentElement.text);
```

and it shows `&#13;`.

If you also output `WScript.Echo(xmlDoc.documentElement.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue);` you get the same value so somehow the entity parsing ends up "converting" the `<!ENTITY eol "<![CDATA[&#xD;&#xA;]]>">` from the DTD subset and the `&eol;` into an entity reference node containing a CDATA section node with a node value where the escaped hexadecimal character reference `&#xD;` is now an escaped decimal one `&#13;`.